# C++ rvalue expression with destructor generates warning C4701 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++, expression, warnings, rvalue

The following C++ code, compiles without warning in Visual Studio 2010:

```
extern void callFunc( int, int );

struct str_wrapper
{
 str_wrapper();
};

extern bool tryParseInt( const str_wrapper& str, int& outValue );

void test()
{
 int x, y;
 if ( tryParseInt( str_wrapper(), x ) && tryParseInt( str_wrapper(), y ) )
 {
  // No warning generated
  callFunc( x, y );
 }
}
```

However if str_wrapper has a user-defined destructor, the code generates the warning on the callFunc(x, y) line:

  warning C4701: potentially uninitialized local variable 'y' used.

```
extern void callFunc( int, int );
```

struct str_wrapper
{
 str_wrapper();
 ~str_wrapper(); ///< Causes warning C4701 below
};

extern bool tryParseInt( const str_wrapper& str, int& outValue );

void test()
{
 int x, y;
 if ( tryParseInt( str_wrapper(), x ) && tryParseInt( str_wrapper(), y ) )
 {
  // C4701 generated for following line
  callFunc( x, y );
 }
}

I would be happy if both examples generated a warning, or if neither example generated a warning.  Am I missing some obscure C++ rule, or is this a compiler bug?

Comment: I'm guessing it was because tryParseInt() takes an int reference, and if the compiler dosen't know what happens in tryParseInt() then it can assume nothing happens to the int reference, leaving it unassigned.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I wasn't able to reproduce that warning with provided code. However, I assume the compiler generates it because of a short-circuit evaluation language feature.

X should be always "initialized" in tryParseInt function, but "initialization" of Y depends only on boolean result from previous tryParseInt(str_wrapper(), x) call. But yeah, it still doesn't make any sense why the warning was generated for line inside an if-block. Maybe the compiler has fooled itself?

Comment: C4701 is a level 4 warning, so make sure you have /W4 or the equivalent in the Visual Studio property pages.

I agree that the code above isn't the best in terms of style and robustness. My main concern is whether this is a false positive at the compiler level, or if there is some difference in the code that causes the warning.  As far as I can tell, callFunc should only be called if tryParseInt was called for both x and y, and both calls succeeded.